# how bread crumb use in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am working with Angularjs, I need to use bread crumb with linking method.

```
smartApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$provide', function($routeProvider, $provide) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            redirectTo: '/dashboard'
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually for breadcrumbs and other css jobs I use bootstrap as do many other people.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#breadcrumbs

Try it.

Or can try this : https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb/wiki/Getting-started